# Can I keep mead/wine in stainless steel bottles?

Tags: bottling, wine, mead, stainless

So what do *you* use for bottling? I'm really starting to look into stainless steel bottles. There are companies that make them (with customized artwork, no less) for conference shwag but you could easily order a small batch and use it for your own goods.

Or can you? My wife seems convinced it won't work. Specifically, her concern is twofold, both related to aging meads/wines in them:

1. The seal may be unreliable. This would no doubt be an issue if you're trying to squirrel away something for a few years.
2. We're not sure how the metal would react with it, long term. We know breweries/wineries ferment in them and maybe do some short-term aging, but what happens to stainless steel after it's been exposed to an alcoholic drink for a few years?

Anyone know much about the behavior of stainless steel in the brewing world?

Crossposted to the homebrewing community on LJ.

Comment: i would like to know its price

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be fine storing wine in a stainless container. It is entirely light proof and air-tight. Beer has been stored and served in stainless steel for many years. You are correct, white wines are fermented in stainless vessels. Reds can be too (they add wood chips to the mix to simulate barrels).

Comment: And if you get the customized bottles, you have great gifts. :-) There is a brand of wine here in the NW that I have seen that is bottled in metal containers. Of course, you'll get the purists in a snit because of the screw top.